# Simultaneous eigenket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, eigenvalue

J. J. Sakurai states in his "Modern Quantum Mechanics", this fact as a theorem ($\pi$ is the parity operator):

> Suppose $$[H,\pi]=0$$
>   and $| n>$ is a nondegenerate eigenket of $H$ with eigenvalue $E_n:$
>   $$H|n> = E_n|n>;$$
>   then $|n>$ is also a parity eigenket.

Then as a proof he uses some fact that is specific to the parity operator.

But isn't this trivially true even if we replace $\pi$ with any other operator if $H$ has a nondegenerate spectrum? is there a case where $H$ commutes with an operator and has nondegenerate eigenket, yet the eigenket is not an eigenket of the other operator?

Is this so if $H$ is not diagonalizable?

Why does this deserve the status of a "theorem"?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104674/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes, this is why I wondered about why Sakurai made a trivially true statement specifically about "parity operator". It seems obviously true, even if we replace $\pi$ with some other operator.